# insert row into gridview from another gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am using VB.net.

I need to fill a gridview(1) with data that cames from another gridview(2), ie:

**(2) - All articles in the database.**

**(1) - Selected articles from (2)**

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the selected row from gridview(2) into a datatable and assign that table as datasource of gridview(1).

Geetha.

Comment: just like that Geetha. Thanks.